# How can I create a D&D 4e Ranger that never misses ranged attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, ranger, ranged-attack

I have a level 12 human ranger who relies mostly on ranged attacks. However I find his attack bonus to be too low. What are the best options to boost my chances of hitting ranged attacks?

I was using Eagle Eyes Goggles, but I recently found that that it only works for ranged basic attacks. I want an option that I can use with my powers.

Comment: Are you interested in simply getting a really high attack bonus, or actually being guaranteed never to miss? Because there *are* "automatic hit" and "same damage if I miss" builds in 4e; maybe not pure ranger, but they exist. (Also, often surprisingly low attack scores turn out to just be missing a number in the math. Are you using the Insider character builder?)

Comment: Could you provide details of your character? Specifically, your to hit and damage when using twin strike (and items and feats contributing to that calculation?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Never miss* is hard to come by, but you can get quite a good attack at your level.**

### Attributes

For an Archer Ranger there is no reason not to put 18 before racial modifiers on Dex. If you are sure you never reach level 14, 17 is sufficient. Increase it every chance you get.
Attack: 6(half level) + 5(attributes) = 11

### Race

Take any race that gives a Dex bonus. If you want to make sure you hit, Elven Accuracy and Heroic Effort (human) is great.
Attack: 11 + 1(racial Dex bonus) = 12

### Weapon

Superior Crossbow has good damage and range, and great accuracy. It is a bit feat intensive, as you need Speed Loader, but at your level you can afford it.
Attack: 12 + 3(proficiency) = 15

### Enhancement

At your level having a +3 Frost weapon is quite reasonable.
Attack: 15+3(enhancement) = 18

### Feats

Crossbow Expertise is a must, depending on your DM and your minor actions, you might also need Speed Loader.
Another feat is needed to get Combat Advantage as often as possible. If you can not convince your melee Leader or Defender to take Vexing Flanker, but they are good at tactical positioning, take Distant Advantage. Otherwise take Wintertouched for accuraty, as you have Lasting Frost for damage. 
Attack: 18 + 2(expertise) + 2(CA) = 22.

### Hit chance

At level 12, an average Standard monster has an AC of 26, a Soldier 28. You can hit it with a roll of 4 and 6, respectively, 85% and 75%. It is quite good, especially combined with Elven Accuracy or Heroic Effort.

**I assumed in all steps that you exclusively use Twin Strike, since that is the only viable choice if you really want to *optimize* your damage. As a Striker you should.**

Answer (score 1):

My build is an elf, with a normal longbow, but I have the feat **Determined Accuracy** which is sort of like an Elven Accuracy for Elven Accuracy, and plus, the feat gives +2 to regular Elven Accuracy.  I have **dual shot arrows** which allows me to roll two d20s and choose either; and the **ghost of the past** theme which is a free action encounter power that also lets me roll two d20s. I have never missed with this build, **ever**.  I also have the proficiencies and expertise for the bow.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site! Check out the [tour] if you haven't already for an overview of how this site works. This seems like it could be good but I agree this needs editing - the first sentence is not comprehensible and should be rephrased.